# How to solve ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Unable to login or register

i tried to remove firebaseuser and changed to authresulths

```
  Future<String> SignIn(String email, String password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)) as FirebaseUser;
    return user.uid;
  }
  Future<String> SignUp(String email, String password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)) as FirebaseUser;
    return user.uid;
  }
```

> flutter (31902): Error = PlatformException(ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND, There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SignUp` method is calling the wrong API. It should call [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html), so:

```
Future<String> SignUp(String email, String password) async{
  AuthResult result = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)) as AuthResult;
  return result.user.uid;
}
```

Comment: Please always share the exact error message you get. In this case, the documentation (https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) shows that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns an `AuthResult`, and we need to unwrap the `User` from that.

Comment: There's an edit link right under your question. Please add as text, no screenshots. Also note that I linked the documentation, so that you can find the basic syntax of the API yourself.

Comment: Searching for the error message gives some helpful hints: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflutter%5D+java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+Failed+resolution+of%3A+Landroid%2Fsupport%2Fv4%2Futil%2FArrayMap%3B